# Service performance vs command line performance

Tags: windows, service, command, kernel

I have a 64 bit application (console app) which I run from the command line, no issues.

Also a 64 bit service app that simply launches the aforementioned console app via CreateProcess and also runs fine.

If the scheduler service creates the job, it will run significantly slower than if I stop the scheduler and decide to run this manually via the command line.  Upwards of 2-3x.  In my tests, service app takes 10 mins.  command line takes 3-4 minutes.  This is consistent; and the workload they are performance are identical.

I tried changing the service to run as the same account I am running it as from the command line .. same issue.

Some things which can be safely removed from the list of possible causes

- This is really as close to apples to apples as I can get .. the same work is being performed by the job every time.
- The system has PLENTY of resources.
- Tons and tons of CPU capacity, memory, IO, IO speed (SSDs), paging etc.
- The service itself is only 10meg and literally does nothing else but wake up every 30 seconds and launch this job. I even tried to just put it as a task under Task Scheduler .. same issue.

I do notice that when I view the job executing via task manager, performance tab .. and I add "kernel time" (View, Show Kernel Times) to the CPU live charts ...

When I view this running via the service; kernel times (red) shows to be like 80-90% of the overall CPU time being used.
When I view this running on the command line, no such issue; kernel time is like 3 to 5%

I am at my wits end as to where to look next.  What could cause this.

Any guidance, suggestions, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should really consider trimming your question down to something more clear and concise. The reaction for many people when they see a wall of text is simply [TL;DR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TL;DR).

Comment: thanks, i trimmed some of the background/commentary and tried to stick to just the relevant points (at least I hope so)

Comment: It is likely that the app is inadvertently doing something that isn't legal in a service session, and isn't handling the error condition properly.  For example, it might be trying to write to stdout or stderr.  I think it is possible to attach a debugger to the console app while it is running in the service session.  At that CPU usage, the odds are good that you'll break into it at the right point.  (If it's a threaded app, first identify the thread that is pegging the CPU so you know which one to examine.)

Comment: Thanks.  I have since tracked it down to something within the OCI for Oracle.  There is a table (35+ fields) that is causing the service performance to severely degrade.  If I simply remove alot of those fields, the scheduler performance is then inline with the commandline.  I am still checking, because I don't have an answer, just a cause still.